Calculating sizeForItemAt for UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
I've been messing around with NASA's Astronomical Picture of the Day API and am attempting to show the images in a collection view with three items per row. As expected, I'm using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. To define the size of each image, I'm using the sizeForItemAt method. High level, I'm taking the width of the collection view, subtracting the padding defined in other delegate methods, and dividing that remaining space by the desired number of columns (3). Surprisingly, it seems my calculations are just slightly off because I only get 2 columns with a pretty hefty space in the middle (and it's not just that some hypothetical images in the middle haven't finished loading!).

Anyone have any idea what is going on here? Here's my code:
    extension ApodCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
       fileprivate enum Constants {
           static let numColumns = 3.0
           static let spacing = 10.0
       }

       /// This gives size of each item.
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.width - ((Constants.numColumns+1)*Constants.spacing)
           let widthPer = availableWidth/Constants.numColumns
           return CGSize(width: widthPer, height: widthPer)
       }

       /// This gives inset around entire collection view.
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
           return UIEdgeInsets(top: Constants.spacing, left: Constants.spacing, bottom: Constants.spacing, right: Constants.spacing)
       }

       /// This gives space between items (horizontal).
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
           return Constants.spacing
       }

       /// This gives space between rows (vertical).
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
           return Constants.spacing
       }
   }

I printed off the collectionView's bounds' width to make sure that wasn't unexpected. It is in fact 402, which is the expected number of points defining the width of an iPhone 16 Pro screen.
Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Could be rounding error. Try return CGSize(width: widthPer.rounded(.down), height: widthPer)

That fixes it! I printed off the widthPer before rounding, and it's 120.66666666666667. I bet that that final 7 (which is rounded up) is what's throwing it off! Crazy, but makes sense! Thanks!
